# Changing the value of x-axis (ordinal) tick values in a D3 grouped chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 grouped bar chart with x-axis formed using my x0 scale which has the domain as the data values. As the domain has data values my tick text is also the same data values. I want to change the tick values to data names keeping my scale unchanged as names can be same but data values are unique.
Please help me to change the tick values.

e.g.  name: 'New Jersey',
      value:'[Calendar]&NewJersey'
I want my axis to be made using the value but the tick text should be name.

http://jsfiddle.net/pragyan88/681q7umb/6

```js
var data = {
  chartTitle: "PopulationByState",
  xAxisLabel: "State",
  yAxisLabel: "Population",
  series: [{
    name: "< 5 Years",
    longName: "Age less than 5 Years",
    value: "i",
    data: [2704659, 2027307, 1208495, 894368, 3157759]
  }, {
    name: "5-13 Years",
    longName: "Age between 5 to 13 years",
    value: "i",
    data: [4704659, 6027307, 808495, 1094368, 2157759]
  }, {
    name: "14-20 Years",
    longName: "Age between 14 to 20 years",
    value: "i",
    data: [1104659, 8027307, 1008495, 394368, 1157759]
  }, {
    name: "21-40 Years",
    longName: "Age between 21 to 40 years",
    value: "i",
    data: [1404659, 2027307, 4208495, 6027307, 5157759]
  }, {
    name: "41-65 Years",
    longName: "Age between 41 to 65 years",
    value: "i",
    data: [2404659, 3027307, 7208495, 8027307, 6157759]
  }, {
    name: ">65 Years",
    longName: "Age greater than 65 years",
    value: "i",
    data: [1404659, 9027307, 4208495, 10027307, 5157759]
  }],

  categories: [{
    name: 'CA',
    longName: 'California',
    value: '[Calendar]&California'
  }, {
    name: "TX",
    longName: 'Texas',
    value: '[Calendar]&Texas'
  }, {
    name: 'NY',
    longName: 'New York',
    value: '[Calendar]&NewYork'
  }, {
    name: "FL",
    longName: 'Florida',
    value: '[Calendar]&Florida'
  }, {
    name: "NJ",
    longName: 'New Jersey',
    value: '[Calendar]&NewJersey'
  }]
}


var format = d3.format('.2s');

var returnArray = [];

var canvasWidth = document.getElementById("chart").offsetWidth,
  canvasHeight = document.getElementById("chart").offsetHeight;

var margin = {
    top: 80,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 30
  },
  width = canvasWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = canvasHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1, 0.2);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var color = ['rgb(218,165,32)', 'rgb(41,95,72)', 'rgb(82,82,20)', 'rgb(43,33,6)', 'rgb(96,35,32)', 'rgb(54,69,79)'];


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickSize(-height, 0, 0);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"))
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "data: <span style='color:green;'>" + d.data[d.index] + "</span><br/>" + "series: <span style='color:yellow;'>" + d.seriesLongName + "</span><br/>" + "category: <span style='color:red;'>" + data.categories[d.index].longName + "</span>";
  });

var legendTip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<span style='color:green;'>" + d.longName + "</span>";
  });

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


for (var i = 0; i < data.series.length; i++) {

  var rgbColor = d3.rgb(color[i]);
  var rgbLighterColor = d3.rgb(color[i]).brighter(4);
  var id = 'gradient' + i;
  var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
    .append("svg:linearGradient")
    .attr('id', id)
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("y2", "100%");

  gradient
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", rgbLighterColor)

  gradient
    .append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", rgbColor)
}


svg.call(tip);
svg.call(legendTip);

x0.domain(data.categories.map(function(d) {
  return d.name;
}));
x1.domain(data.series.map(function(d) {
  return d.name
})).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.series, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d.data);
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("x", -15)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr('class', 'chartLabel')
  .text(data.yAxisLabel)

var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
  .data(data.categories)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "state")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.name) + ",0)";
  });

var bars = state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d, i) {
    var rArray = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < data.series.length; x++) {
      rArray.push({
        name: data.series[x].name,
        data: data.series[x].data,
        index: i,
        seriesLongName: data.series[x].longName
      });
    }

    return rArray;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .on('click', function(d) {
    if (d3.event.ctrlKey) {
      if (d3.select(this).style('opacity') == 1) {
        returnArray.push({
          categoryName: data.categories[d.index].name,
          seriesName: d.name,
          data: d.data[d.index]
        });
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5);
      } else {
        returnArray.forEach(function(obj, i) {
          if (obj.categoryName == data.categories[d.index].name && obj.seriesName == d.name && obj.data == d.data[d.index])
            returnArray.splice(i, 1);
        });
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1);
      }
    } else {
      var rect = svg.selectAll('rect');
      rect.forEach(function(rec) {
        rec.forEach(function(r) {
          returnArray = [];
          r.style.opacity = 1;
        })
      });
      if (d3.select(this).style('opacity') == 1) {
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5);
        returnArray.push({
          categoryName: data.categories[d.index].name,
          seriesName: d.name,
          data: d.data[d.index]
        });
      }
    }

  })
  .on('contextmenu', function(d) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    alert(d.name);
  })
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
  .attr('class', 'bar')
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", height)
  .attr("height", 0)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return "url(#gradient" + i + ")"
  });


bars.transition()
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return y(d.data[d.index]);
  })
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return height - y(d.data[d.index]);
  })
  .delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * 250;
  }).ease('elastic');


svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom / 2) + ")")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr('class', 'chartLabel')
  .text(data.xAxisLabel);

svg.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + "0)")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr('class', 'chartTitle')
  .text(data.chartTitle);


d3.select("svg").on('contextmenu', function() {
  var d3_target = d3.select(d3.event.target);
  if (!d3_target.classed("bar")) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    alert('I m the body!!')
  }
});

d3.select("svg").on('click', function() {
  var d3_target = d3.select(d3.event.target);
  if (!(d3_target.classed("bar") || d3_target.classed("legend"))) {
    returnArray = [];
    var rect = svg.selectAll('rect');
    rect.forEach(function(rec) {
      rec.forEach(function(r) {
        r.style.opacity = 1;
      })
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class='watermark'>
    <div id="chart" style="width:300px;height:400px;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the json structure of the the input data in question, using the following line for x-axis helped:

```js
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("id", "xaxis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.selectAll('text')
.text(function (d,i) {
   return data.categories[i].name;
})
```

Comment: I also used the category values to construct my x-scale and thus x-axis